# Is a subspace closed?

Tags: functional-analysis, vector-spaces

Let $X$ be a topological vector space,$N$ a subspace.Is $N$ closed in the topology of $X$ if $X/N$ is closed in its suitable toplogy?\par
Note that every singleton of $X$ is a closed set,so I think $N$ should be closed in order to make $x+N$ closed.Is it right?

Comment: What topology would you put on $X/N$ that would not make it closed? The right property is that the quotient topology be Hausdorff, which is equivalent to $N$ being closed.

Comment: Also, since $\phi(n) = x+n$ is a homeomorphism, $N$ is closed iff $\phi(N) = \{x\}+N$ is closed.

Comment: If $N$ is a clsoed subspace of $X$,then $X/N$ is a topological vector space with a topology induced from the topology of $X$.Here I ask the inverse problem.

Comment: @mathon I am afraid you did not understand the comments. Any topology of a set $Y$ makes $Y$ closed by the first axiom of a topology which requires that $\emptyset$ and $Y$ be open, whence closed. So the condition "$X/N$ is closed in its suitable topology" is empty. Note also that some authors allow topological vector spaces not to be Hausdorff (which is equivalent to T1="closed singletons" for tvs). So you don't necessarily have that singletons are closed in $X$. But is is still true that $X/N$ is Hausdorff iff $N$ is closed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As explained in comments by julien and copper.hat, the following properties are equivalent:

1. $N$ is closed in $X$
2. The singleton $[N]$ is closed in $X/N$

Indeed,  consider the quotient map $\pi:X\to X/N$. By the definition of quotient topology, closed subsets of $X/N$ are precisely those sets whose preimages under $\pi$ are closed in $X$. The preimage of  the singleton $[N]\in X/N$ under $\pi$ is $ N$. Hence the stated equivalence.

Comment: This equivalence shows that $N$ is closed iff $X/N$ is T1. It might be interesting to note that it is also equivalent to $X/N$ being T2. As $T1\iff T2$ for topological vector spaces.